# How to get a value in an object in Java?

Tags: java

Let's say I have something like this :

```
public class obj{
    public int x;
    public obj(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

and this :

```
public class main{

    obj o = new obj(1);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //get the value of OBJ
        //add 1 to the value got from above(let's just say I wanted to. no reason why)
    }

}
```

is there a possible way to get the value of the obj's x value without changing the x to static? And make it so that you can change it? when I try to do something like this, it always says to change the x to static. why? I know this may be a weird question but i just wanted to know :)

Comment: You want to access the non-static variable `o` in the static method `main`? Why should that be possible?

Comment: `public class obj(){...}` -is this even compiling in java?

Comment: srry, I wash sort of rushing while writing. ill fix that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your object to `static` first since you are accessing it directly from `static main`.

```
private static obj o = new obj(1);

// You can get the value of `x` from `o` as follows:
int x = o.x;

// You can increment the value in the object `o` as follows:
o.x++;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your class declaration is wrong. You don't use parenthesis in class declaration.

Also, in Java you write class names big. (The class Object already exists, don't make a class "Obj" because it would mean the same and is an abbreviation.)

```
public class MyObject {
    public int x;
    public MyObject(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
}


public class Main {

    MyObject myInstance = new MyObject(1);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // You can just do ++ behind the variable. This adds +1.
        myInstance.x++;
        // If you want to get the value of the (public) variable x:
        int temp = myInstance.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you rename the class, then also rename the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get it by using

```
o.x
```

It is not telling you to change `x` to `static`. It is telling you to make `o` to static. `o` is non-static and cannot be used in the static main method.

Comment: oh yeah! i forgot about thinking about that simple thing! :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Non-static instances can't be assessed in static method directly. Since `o` is an instance variable rather than static variable, you will need to create an instance of `Main` to access it's non-static variable.

```
public class Main {

    Obj o = new Obj(1);
    public static void main(String[] args){

      Main main = new Main();
      main.o.x += 1; 

    }

}
```